# Python, image compression and multiprocessing

Tags: python, imagemagick, multiprocessing

I'm trying to wrap my head round MultiProcessing in Python, but I simply can't. Notice that I was, am and probably forever be a noob in everything-programming. Ah, anyways. Here it goes.

I'm writing a Python script that compresses images downloaded to a folder with ImageMagick, using predefined variables from the user, stored in an ini file. The script searches for folders matching a pattern in a download dir, checks if they contain JPGs, PNGs or other image files and, if yes, recompresses and renames them, storing the results in a "compressed" folder.

Now, here's the thing: I'd love it if I was able to "parallelize" the whole compression thingy, but... I can't understand how I'm supposed to do that.

I don't want to tire you with the existing code since it simply sucks. It's just a simple "for file in directory" loop. THAT's what I'd love to parallelize - could somebody give me an example on how multiprocessing could be used with files in a directory?

I mean, let's take this simple piece of code:

for f in matching_directory:
    print ('I\'m going to process file:', f)

For those that DO have to peek at the code, here's the part where I guess the whole parallelization bit will stick:

```
for f in ImageFolders:
    print (splitter)
    print (f)
    print (splitter)
    PureName = CleanName(f)
    print (PureName)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(f):
        padding = int(round( math.log( len(files), 10))) + 1
        padding = max(minpadding, padding)
        filecounter = 0
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png')):
                filecounter += 1
                imagefile, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
                newfilename = "%s_%s%s" % (PureName, (str(filecounter).rjust(padding,'0')), '.jpg')
                startfilename = os.path.join (f, filename)
                finalfilename = os.path.join(Dir_Images_To_Publish, PureName, newfilename)
                print (filecounter, ':', startfilename, ' >>> ', finalfilename)
                Original_Image_FileList.append(startfilename)
                Processed_Image_FileList.append(finalfilename)
```

...and here I'd like to be able to add a piece of code where a worker takes the first file from Original_Image_FileList and compresses it to the first filename from Processed_Image_FileList, a second one takes the one after that, blah-blah, up to a specific number of workers - depending on a user setting in the ini file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note, you might like to read a style guide to improve the readability of your code, for example, the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html).

Comment: It may sound funny, but even those simple instructions on "how to style what I write" seemed too advanced for me. Yeah, some things are obvious and I get them, but others I cannot grok due to not being familiar enough with coding in Python and understanding all terms - I'm also Greek, so language _is_ a barrier sometimes, when I don't know if "an unknown word" is part of the instructions of the writer or the programming language itself.

I _have_ to admit, though, that the biggest problem is that I didn't start learning from scratch, but jumped into a project and started expanding from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pool of workers using the `Pool` class, to which you can distribute the image compression to. See the [Using a pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) section of the `multiprocessing` documentation.

If your compression function is called `compress(filename)`, for example, then you can use the `Pool.map` method to apply this function to an iterable that returns the filenames, i.e. your list `matching_directory`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def compress_image(image):
  """Define how you'd like to compress `image`..."""
  pass

def distribute_compression(images, pool_size = 4):
  with Pool(processes=pool_size) as pool:
    pool.map(compress_image, images)
```

There's a variety of map-like methods available, see [map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) for starters. You may like to experiment with the pool size, to see what works best.

Comment: At last, I understood the whole concept. Problem is, as I mentioned in my comment above to Patrick, I'm a total noob and started learning "by creating a project of my own". I find that this way It's easier for me to understand how a concept works, but it's also like spreading a thin sheet, full of holes, as "a project", and then trying to patch them one by one, learning as you go.

I mention this 'cause although "I got" your code, now I don't know how to "call it". Every tutorial I met mentions calling a function and returning a value. I deal with files. Why should I print a value?!